# Implement zoom with WM_TOUCH

Tags: c++, visual-c++, touch, zooming, wm-touch

I need to implement a zoom in/out in a Windows Apllication which runs on a multi-touch screen.

After some progress, I understand I can't have both WM_GESTURE and WM_TOUCH at the same time.
Before I was catching WM_GESTURE and then checking if GID_ZOOM was being sent, but know I must zoom in and out another way.

How should I implement this now using WM_TOUCH?

Thank you all!

Comment: You shouldn't.   Unless you're developing exclusively for Windows 7, you should be using [WM_POINTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790602/wm-touch-vs-wm-pointer) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately it's exclusisvely for windows 7. I achieved what I wanted with WM_TOUCH API, using IManipulationProcessor and ManipulationEventSink. Not easy but it works very well. Thanks!